# macOS thinks Option key is pressed

Tags: catalina

After some time of inactivity, the keyboard - Microsoft Ergonomic Keyboard - starts acting as if the Option (Win) key is pressed. Pressing the key does not reset its state. The only solution is to flip the keyboard over, and take out the battery for a couple of seconds. Started happening after upgrading to Catalina 10.15.7.

It happens pretty regularly, but only if the computer is idle for maybe 10+ mins.

Anyone seen this?

UPDATE: This only happens on the external keyboard, the built-in keyboard is fine. It's probably a bug in Karabiner Elements, which I had to upgrade after upgrading the OS.

UPDATE: It wasn't Karabiner, I uninstalled it. Sounds like a keyboard driver bug.

Comment: Option is not Win.  Option is Alt.  Win is Command.  Which is it??  What is happening on your machine?

Comment: @Tom The MS Ergonomic Keyboard has these keys: [Win] [Alt] [Space] [Alt] [Win]. The Win key is mapped to Option (⌥), and Alt to Command (⌘).

Comment: So when you press the Win key and type asdfg, you see åß∂ƒ© (that's the US layout)?

Comment: @TomGewecke Yes. But normally, when I let go of Win, it goes back to normal. The issue is that sometimes the keyboard gets stuck in this state, and pressing the Win key does not get it unstuck.

Comment: It would be useful to know if you have similar problems when using a different keyboard.

Comment: @TomGewecke, I updated the question. It's only affecting the external keyboard. I've uninstalled Karabiner to see if it makes a difference.